# Dart removeWhere on second/temp variable affects origin

Tags: dart

I want to use `removeWhere` on the *second/temp* variable without affecting the *origin* variable.

```dart
void main() {  
  Map<String, dynamic> testMap = {
    'first': {'value': 1},
    'second': {'value': 2},
    'third': {'value': 3},
  };
  
  print(testMap);
  
  Map<String, dynamic> tempMap = testMap;
  tempMap.removeWhere((k,v) => v['value'] > 1);
  
  print(testMap);
  print(tempMap);
}
```

The output for print will be:

```
{first: {value: 1}, second: {value: 2}, third: {value: 3}}
{first: {value: 1}}
{first: {value: 1}}
```

Why is `removeWhere` affecting the *origin* variable? When I'm calling it on `tempMap`

**EDIT:** As responded in the comment by OMi Shah, the fastest way would be:

```dart
Map<String, dynamic> tempMap = {...testMap};
```

Comment: because you're not copying the values to the new variable, instead you're copying the reference of the old variable in the new variable.

Comment: Ok, I understand this, but how can I make it work?

Comment: ``Map<String, dynamic> tempMap = {...testMap};`` instead of ``Map<String, dynamic> tempMap = testMap;``

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a new map. In your specific case, we could just create a new map from the original where we at creation will filter out the key-value pairs you don't want.

So something like this:

```
void main() {
  Map<String, dynamic> testMap = {
    'first': {'value': 1},
    'second': {'value': 2},
    'third': {'value': 3},
  };

  print(testMap); // {first: {value: 1}, second: {value: 2}, third: {value: 3}}

  Map<String, dynamic> tempMap = {
    for (final entry in testMap.entries)
      if (entry.value['value'] <= 1) entry.key: entry.value
  };

  print(testMap); // {first: {value: 1}, second: {value: 2}, third: {value: 3}}
  print(tempMap); // {first: {value: 1}}
}
```

Comment: the spread syntax will be simpler and efficient  ig, sir?

Comment: @OMiShah You cannot use spread, in my example, since you want to filter the data on a map. The `...` operator does only work on `Map` and not `Entry` objects (in the context of creating a `Map`).

Comment: actually, you're right, sir. If no manipulation is needed then the spread way is correct. never mind, sir. BTW, spread syntax works for maps too.

Comment: Want to mention that it works perfectly with spread.

Comment: @PhiliposD. Yes, if you don't want to filter any of the elements from the `Map`, you can totally fine use spread to create a copy of your `Map` and then call `removeWhere()`. My solution is just showing that we can prevent the creation of a full copy of the `Map` but instead create a new `Map` containing the data we want and preventing the call of `removeWhere()`.

Comment: @julemand101 yes I've seen in the code what is happening, but I wanted to manipulate using the `removeWhere` method. Although also your answer can give the same output in the end, but without `removeWhere`

Comment: @PhiliposD. And that is fine. Just notice that `removeWhere()` is not that efficient since we need to iterate over the full `Map`. So your solution require us to iterate over the `Map` twice (first to copy, then to remove) while my suggested solution would only do it once. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use Map.from

```
    Map<String, dynamic> testMap = {
      'first': {'value': 1},
      'second': {'value': 2},
      'third': {'value': 3},
    };
    
    Map<String, dynamic> tempMap = Map.from(testMap);
    tempMap.removeWhere((k,v) => v['value'] > 1);

    print(testMap);
    print(tempMap);
```

Comment: or simply ``Map<String, dynamic> tempMap = {...testMap};``